# Create Tables from input data on runtime in EF Core

Tags: npgsql, ef-core-2.2

I have multiple dozen of table definitions and data in text form.
The table definitions could also change from time to time.

I would like to create EF Core tables from theese definitions at runtime and fill them from these files.

Migration would be also nice if possible.

Is this Possible?

Alternatively: Is it possible to SQL"Create Table xyz" from a DatabaseContext?

Or should i better just use plain (Npg)sqlCommands to create, insert and update?

I am using Npgsql btw.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to execute your own SQL to create your tables, then it doesn't really matter if you do it with NpgsqlCommand (ADO.NET) or EF Core. EF Core doesn't really have any added value for executing that kind of raw SQL, so you're probably better off just using NpgsqlCommands. However, it's your responsibility to make sure your EF Core code model corresponds exactly to your text definitions. Either you manually make sure of that (by maintaining a C# class model that corresponds exactly), or you can reverse-engineer the model from the database created from your definition).

However, migrations are a very different thing. If the idea is to keep the external table definitions and even evolve them, then migrations don't really make sense - your external definitions are your single source of truth on the schema, and everything is derived from that. If you want to work with EF Core migrations, then your C# model must be your single source of truth - you make changes on that and the database is updated.

Note that there's [an issue open](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/831) on updating a code model from an existing database - this would allow you to make changes on your database (via your external definitions?) and update the code model, instead of regenerating it from scratch. However this isn't implemented yet.